# How to do jobs for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, jobs

I have to do a job that determines if there is a .json or .csv file and imports it into a Mongo database. But I don't know how to do a job. Can somebody help me?

The database is configured with a Mongo sharding with 3 Shards. (TestSharding). The database is configured with a Mongo sharding with 3 Shards. (TestSharding) and the script can be bash

Comment: If you need help you have to specify how you want to achieve that - with bash script, script in other programming language and etc. Specify what is your setup and what you want to achieve. Please edit your question with more information about it.

Comment: The database is configured with a Mongo sharding with 3 Shards. (TestSharding). The database is configured with a Mongo sharding with 3 Shards. (TestSharding) and the script can be bash.

Comment: if you need to execute periodical job in linux, the easiest is to create bash script and add it to your crontab as cronjob, if your database is sharded the job need to load the data via the mongos ( mongodb sharded cluster routing service)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create bash script that will check if file is csv or json and will start mongoimport command with the necessary parameters and will move the file to other dir when is loaded.
   Lets suppose the files you want to check are located inside /pathToFile/ folder and after importing the file you need to move them to /pathToImportedFiles/ .

Your bash script can start as follow:

```
for fname in $(find /pathToFIle/* -maxdepth 1 -type f) 
    do  
    if [[ $file == *.csv ]]; mongoimport csv ;fi;
    if [[ $file == *.json ]]; mongoimport json  ;fi;
done
```

example mongoimport json file:

```
mongoimport --port 27017 --db theDatabase --collection theCollection --file /pathToFile/theJsonFile.json --jsonArray
```

example mongoimport csv file:

```
mongoimport --port 27017 --db theDatabase --collection theCollection --type csv --fields "a,b,c" --file /pathToFile/theCsvFile.csv
```

2. Add the bash script to your app user crontab(crontab -e ) with the necessary periodicity.
   Your crontab entry to check and load files at 05:30h every day may look as follow:

   30 05 * * * /pathToScript/loader.sh